# Rename command seemed to remove a bunch of files. Can I recover them?

Tags: rename, data-recovery

Using Ubuntu 22.04

I had a folder with a bunch of files I wanted to change the file extension so I used:

`rename 's/\.zip$/\.cbz/' *.zip`

The command completed without throwing any errors, but I found about 2/3 of my files were missing after. I think it had to do with the names of some the files containing brackets or quotes but I know some missing files had very simple names (`comic5.zip`) and I see that every file who's name started with a bracket is now missing.

<s>I tried using photorec to recover the files but it couldn't find a single one of them.</s>

The folder size is a lot smaller now which seems to indicate they got deleted <s>but if that were the case I would've thought photorec would be able to recover at least some of them</s>. Just using my file explorer, the folder was ~120GB before running the command and ~40GB after. Unfortunately I didn't look at the actual number of files before the command, but I could also tell just by scrolling through that there are much fewer files.

Does anyone know what happened to the files and if they can be recovered?

```
$ rename -V
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 1.30, File::Rename::Options version 1.10
```

Update:

Turns out I forgot to change some of my previous settings in photorec, I ran it again and it did find the missing files, pretty sure all files are recovered now. I think that confirms the files were in fact deleted. Still not exactly sure how it happened but I think Stéphane's explanation is the most likely.

In any case, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ touch {comic5,{a..d}}.zip './--e=BEGIN{unlink for <c*>}#.zip'
$ ls
 a.zip   b.zip   comic5.zip   c.zip   d.zip  '--e=BEGIN{unlink for <c*>}#.zip'
```

```
$ rename 's/\.zip$/\.cbz/' *.zip
$ ls
 a.zip   b.zip   d.zip  '--e=BEGIN{unlink for <c*>}#.zip'
```

Oops! All the files whose name starts with `c` have been removed.

For the `File::Rename` implementation of `rename`, this kind of issue was [fixed in 1.99](https://metacpan.org/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-2.01/source/Changes#L60) (on my request) but Ubuntu 22.04 comes with version 1.30.

Here, you'd want instead:

```
rename 's/\.zip\z/\.cbz/' ./*.zip
```

With that `./` prefix preventing any of the zip file names from being taken as an option by `rename`¹.

Or, with that particular implementation of `rename`, pass the file list via its standard input instead of arguments:

```
printf '%s\0' *.zip | rename -0 's/\.zip/\.cbz/'
```

Which with shells where `printf` is builtin (most) also works around the *`Argument list too long`* limit.

Or use `zsh`'s `zmv` instead which doesn't have this kind of problem, has some extra safeguards and is generally easier to use²:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(*).zip' '$1.cbz'
```

Now, this kind of thing is unlikely to happen by  chance. If that's what happened, someone would have planted a malicious similarly named file in the current directory with the knowledge that you would run such a command.

If the malicious code did `unlink()` or if the files were removed as the result of a `rename()` replacing the file, you might have some luck using [some filesystem undelete/recovery approach](/q/80270). If it did the equivalent of what `shred`/`wipe` do or encrypted the contents before moving the files elsewhere as ransomware would do, your best option would be restoring from backup.

In the absence of malicious file names, `rename` should not normally lose data as it checks whether the target file exists before renaming. You might lose symlink files though if the target of those symlinks are not accessible as [`rename` uses `-e <the-target>`](https://metacpan.org/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-1.30/source/lib/File/Rename.pm#L42) and that would return false for a symlink that doesn't resolve like for the `-e` of the `[` utility:

```
$ touch a.zip
$ ln -s /x a.bcz
$ ls -n
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000 2 Dec 22 08:39 a.bcz -> /x
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Dec 22 08:39 a.zip
```

```
$ rename -v 's/\.zip$/\.bcz/' *.zip
a.zip renamed as a.bcz
$ ls -n
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Dec 22 08:39 a.bcz
```

Oops! That (broken) `a.bcz` symlink is gone.

But symlinks take very little space on disk, so that couldn't explain the 80 out of 120GiB loss that you suffered from.

Like Chris, I suspect your problem was elsewhere. Your files may even still be there, only not in the directory you think they should be. Try a `sudo find / -iname 'comic5.zip' -o -iname 'comic5.cbz'`

---

<sup>¹ Also note the `\z` in place of `$` which you generally want to use in regexps that match things other than *lines* as `$` matches either at the end of the subject (which you want here) or before a newline character at the end of the subject (which you don't want though in this particular case, the subject ends in `.zip` and not newline, so that wouldn't be a problem).</sup>

<sup>² even if generally slower as it calls one `mv` per file. Though you can run `zmodload zsh/files` to get a builtin `mv`.</sup>

Comment: I confirmed that the files were deleted and managed to recovered them. In my situation, it's more likely a coincidence than something intentionally malicious, but you're initial explanation seems to be the most likely. I'll update if I happen to find the guilty filename(s). I'll make sure to use the other options you described in the future. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the command that you ran:

> ```
> rename 's/\.zip$/\.cbz/' *.zip
> ```

This changes the last four characters of every file or directory<sup>*</sup> name matching the glob pattern `*.zip` in the current directory from `.zip` to `.cbz`. That's all. It uses a Perl substitution expression to perform this rename.

Furthermore, at least on my system, `rename` will refuse to rename an item (file) where the target name already exists:

```
touch a.zip a.zap
rename 's/\.zip$/.zap/' *.zip
a.zip not renamed: a.zap already exists
```

> I found about 2/3 of my files were missing after

I cannot see anything reasonable<sup>+</sup> in the scenario that you have described that would cause files (or directories, etc.) to disappear. Perhaps there was another command such as `mv`, that does not perform sanity checks before overwrite. Check your `history` to see what that shows you

---

<sup>* Actually it'll rename any type of item, whether regular file, directory, device, pipe... but only where it matches the criteria I've described</sup>

<sup>+ Files starting with a dash (`-`) or double dash (`--`) are always problematic. Here too unless you protect your file patterns by separating command arguments and file arguments with a standalone `--`, or by using a modified `./name` format instead of plain `name`. For example `mv -- -a dasha` to rename `-a` to `dash`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm positive there were no other commands as I noticed the size of the folder immediately before and after running the command. I just checked my history and there was nothing either.

I tested it and you are right that rename will not replace files with the same name, but either way, the files are definitely not there.

Comment: @image_muck, "_the size of the folder_" - what measure did you use?

Comment: Just using my file explorer, the folder was ~120GB before running the command and ~40GB after. Unfortunately I didn't look at the actual number of files before the command, but I could also tell just by scrolling through that there are much fewer files. I also noticed every file that started with a bracket is now missing, which is why I mentioned it in the question. There were also several files that I remember by name that aren't there anymore. I can't say whether or not the drive itself reduced in size since I didn't check that beforehand though.